# Upload image along with other parameters using AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, xml, file-upload, base64, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to send an image from my app to a server. This is a windows server with .net web services.

The service I'm trying to call receives three parameters: A numeric identifier (user Id) to tell the server which user is sending the new picture, the image as a base64 Encoded string, and the image format, which is always a .png.

My upload function is:

```
- (void)updateProfilePic:(UIImage *)profilePic forUser:(User *)user
{
    //Encode the image in the requested format
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePic);
    NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions: NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    //Build the URL string
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:BaseURL];

    NSString *soapBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                          "<soap:Body>\n"
                          "<UpdateUserProfilePic_iOS xmlns=\"http://mycompany.com/webservices/>\n"
                          "<userId>%d</userId>\n"
                          "<imgbinStr>%@</imgbinStr>\n"
                          "<imgFormat>.png</imgFormat>\n"
                          "</UpdateUserProfilePic_iOS>\n"
                          "</soap:Body>\n"
                          "</soap:Envelope>",
                          (int)user.userId, encodedString];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapBody length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[soapBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue:@"\"http://mycompany.com/webservices/UpdateUserProfilePic_iOS\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
        //parse NSXMLParser object here if request successful
        if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSXMLParser class]]) {
            XMLParser *xml = [[XMLParser alloc] init];
            NSString *responseString = [xml parseResponse:responseObject];
            NSLog(@"Update picture response: %@", responseString);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

So far, the response is an error. However, error is 400, which makes me think that the problem is with the way I'm formatting my request:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x7999aa20 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x799858c0> { URL: http://myserverIP/UserProfileSvc.asmx } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 16 Oct 2014 00:03:53 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myserverIP/UserProfileSvc.asmx, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<>}
```

I don't think the problem is on the server side. I'm probably formatting something incorrectly, but I don't know what that may be. Thanks in advance

Comment: hiii have you found solution for this? I'm having the same problem